# Squid + Dans Guardian (simple configuration)

Tags: linux, squid

I just built a new proxy server and compiled the latest versions of squid and dansguardian. We use basic authentication to select what users are allowed outside of our network. It seems squid is working just fine and accepts my username and password and lets me out.

But if i connect to dans guardian, it prompts for username and password and then displays a message saying my username is not allowed to access the internet. Its pulling my username for the error message so i know it knows who i am. The part i get confused on is i thought that part was handled all by squid, and squid is working flawlessly.

Can someone please double check my config files and tell me if i'm missing something or there is some new option i must set to get this to work.

dansguardian.conf

```
# Web Access Denied Reporting (does not affect logging)
#
# -1 = log, but do not block - Stealth mode
#  0 = just say 'Access Denied'
#  1 = report why but not what denied phrase
#  2 = report fully
#  3 = use HTML template file (accessdeniedaddress ignored) - recommended
# reportinglevel = 3

# Language dir where languages are stored for internationalisation.
# The HTML template within this dir is only used when reportinglevel
# is set to 3. When used, DansGuardian will display the HTML file instead of
# using the perl cgi script.  This option is faster, cleaner
# and easier to customise the access denied page.
# The language file is used no matter what setting however.
# languagedir = '/etc/dansguardian/languages'

# language to use from languagedir. language = 'ukenglish'

# Logging Settings
#
# 0 = none  1 = just denied  2 = all text based  3 = all requests loglevel
= 3

# Log Exception Hits
# Log if an exception (user, ip, URL, phrase) is matched and so
# the page gets let through.  Can be useful for diagnosing
# why a site gets through the filter.  on | off logexceptionhits = on

# Log File Format
# 1 = DansGuardian format        2 = CSV-style format
# 3 = Squid Log File Format      4 = Tab delimited logfileformat = 1


# Log file location
# 
# Defines the log directory and filename.
#loglocation = '/var/log/dansguardian/access.log'


# Network Settings
# 
# the IP that DansGuardian listens on.  If left blank DansGuardian will
# listen on all IPs.  That would include all NICs, loopback, modem, etc.
# Normally you would have your firewall protecting this, but if you want
# you can limit it to only 1 IP.  Yes only one. filterip =

# the port that DansGuardian listens to. filterport = 8080

# the ip of the proxy (default is the loopback - i.e. this server) proxyip =
127.0.0.1

# the port DansGuardian connects to proxy on proxyport = 3128

# accessdeniedaddress is the address of your web server to which the cgi
# dansguardian reporting script was copied
# Do NOT change from the default if you are not using the cgi.
# accessdeniedaddress = 'http://YOURSERVER.YOURDOMAIN/cgi-bin/dansguardian.pl'

# Non standard delimiter (only used with accessdeniedaddress)
# Default is enabled but to go back to the original standard mode dissable it. nonstandarddelimiter = on



# Banned image replacement
# Images that are banned due to domain/url/etc reasons including those
# in the adverts blacklists can be replaced by an image.  This will,
# for example, hide images from advert sites and remove broken image
# icons from banned domains.
# 0 = off
# 1 = on (default) usecustombannedimage = 1 custombannedimagefile = '/etc/dansguardian/transparent1x1.gif'



# Filter groups options
# filtergroups sets the number of filter groups. A filter group is a set of content
# filtering options you can apply to a group of users.  The value must be 1 or more.
# DansGuardian will automatically look for dansguardianfN.conf where N is the filter
# group.  To assign users to groups use the filtergroupslist option.  All users default
# to filter group 1.  You must have some sort of authentication to be able to map users
# to a group.  The more filter groups the more copies of the lists will be in RAM so
# use as few as possible. filtergroups = 1 filtergroupslist = '/etc/dansguardian/filtergroupslist'



# Authentication files location bannediplist = '/etc/dansguardian/bannediplist' exceptioniplist = '/etc/dansguardian/exceptioniplist' banneduserlist = '/etc/dansguardian/banneduserlist' exceptionuserlist = '/etc/dansguardian/exceptionuserlist'



# Show weighted phrases found
# If enabled then the phrases found that made up the total which excedes
# the naughtyness limit will be logged and, if the reporting level is
# high enough, reported. on | off showweightedfound = on

# Weighted phrase mode
# There are 3 possible modes of operation:
# 0 = off = do not use the weighted phrase feature.
# 1 = on, normal = normal weighted phrase operation.
# 2 = on, singular = each weighted phrase found only counts once on a page.
# weightedphrasemode = 2



# Positive result caching for text URLs
# Caches good pages so they don't need to be scanned again
# 0 = off (recommended for ISPs with users with disimilar browsing)
# 1000 = recommended for most users
# 5000 = suggested max upper limit urlcachenumber = 
#
# Age before they are stale and should be ignored in seconds
# 0 = never
# 900 = recommended = 15 mins urlcacheage = 



# Smart and Raw phrase content filtering options
# Smart is where the multiple spaces and HTML are removed before phrase filtering
# Raw is where the raw HTML including meta tags are phrase filtered
# CPU usage can be effectively halved by using setting 0 or 1
# 0 = raw only
# 1 = smart only
# 2 = both (default) phrasefiltermode = 2



# Lower casing options
# When a document is scanned the uppercase letters are converted to lower case
# in order to compare them with the phrases.  However this can break Big5 and
# other 16-bit texts.  If needed preserve the case.  As of version
2.7.0 accented
# characters are supported.
# 0 = force lower case (default)
# 1 = do not change case preservecase = 0



# Hex decoding options
# When a document is scanned it can optionally convert %XX to chars.
# If you find documents are getting past the phrase filtering due to encoding
# then enable.  However this can break Big5 and other 16-bit texts.
# 0 = disabled (default)
# 1 = enabled hexdecodecontent = 0



# Force Quick Search rather than DFA search algorithm
# The current DFA implementation is not totally 16-bit character compatible
# but is used by default as it handles large phrase lists much faster.
# If you wish to use a large number of 16-bit character phrases then
# enable this option.
# 0 = off (default)
# 1 = on (Big5 compatible) forcequicksearch = 0



# Reverse lookups for banned site and URLs.
# If set to on, DansGuardian will look up the forward DNS for an IP URL
# address and search for both in the banned site and URL lists.  This would
# prevent a user from simply entering the IP for a banned address.
# It will reduce searching speed somewhat so unless you have a local caching
# DNS server, leave it off and use the Blanket IP Block option in the
# bannedsitelist file instead. reverseaddresslookups = off



# Reverse lookups for banned and exception IP lists.
# If set to on, DansGuardian will look up the forward DNS for the IP
# of the connecting computer.  This means you can put in hostnames in
# the exceptioniplist and bannediplist.
# It will reduce searching speed somewhat so unless you have a local DNS server, 
# leave it off. reverseclientiplookups = off



# Build bannedsitelist and bannedurllist cache files.
# This will compare the date stamp of the list file with the date stamp of
# the cache file and will recreate as needed.
# If a bsl or bul .processed file exists, then that will be used instead.
# It will increase process start speed by 300%.  On slow computers this will
# be significant.  Fast computers do not need this option. on | off createlistcachefiles = on



# POST protection (web upload and forms)
# does not block forms without any file upload, i.e. this is just for
# blocking or limiting uploads
# measured in kibibytes after MIME encoding and header bumph
# use 0 for a complete block
# use higher (e.g. 512 = 512Kbytes) for limiting
# use -1 for no blocking
#maxuploadsize = 512
#maxuploadsize = 0 maxuploadsize = -1



# Max content filter page size
# Sometimes web servers label binary files as text which can be very
# large which causes a huge drain on memory and cpu resources.
# To counter this, you can limit the size of the document to be
# filtered and get it to just pass it straight through.
# This setting also applies to content regular expression modification.
# The size is in Kibibytes - eg 2048 = 2Mb
# use 0 for no limit maxcontentfiltersize = 



# Username identification methods (used in logging)
# You can have as many methods as you want and not just one.  The first one
# will be used then if no username is found, the next will be used.
# * proxyauth is for when basic proxy authentication is used (no good for
#   transparent proxying).
# * ntlm is for when the proxy supports the MS NTLM authentication
#   protocol.  (Only works with IE5.5 sp1 and later).  **NOT IMPLEMENTED**
# * ident is for when the others don't work.  It will contact the computer
#   that the connection came from and try to connect to an identd server
#   and query it for the user owner of the connection. usernameidmethodproxyauth = on usernameidmethodntlm = off # **NOT IMPLEMENTED** usernameidmethodident = off



# Preemptive banning - this means that if you have proxy auth enabled and a user accesses
# a site banned by URL for example they will be denied straight away without a request
# for their user and pass.  This has the effect of requiring the user to visit a clean
# site first before it knows who they are and thus maybe an admin user.
# This is how DansGuardian has always worked but in some situations it is less than
# ideal.  So you can optionally disable it.  Default is on.
# As a side effect disabling this makes AD image replacement work better as the mime
# type is know. preemptivebanning = on



# Misc settings

# if on it adds an X-Forwarded-For: <clientip> to the HTTP request
# header.  This may help solve some problem sites that need to know the
# source ip. on | off forwardedfor = on


# if on it uses the X-Forwarded-For: <clientip> to determine the client
# IP. This is for when you have squid between the clients and DansGuardian.
# Warning - headers are easily spoofed. on | off usexforwardedfor = off


# if on it logs some debug info regarding fork()ing and accept()ing which
# can usually be ignored.  These are logged by syslog.  It is safe to leave
# it on or off logconnectionhandlingerrors = on



# Fork pool options

# sets the maximum number of processes to sporn to handle the incomming
# connections.  Max value usually 250 depending on OS.
# On large sites you might want to try 180. maxchildren = 180


# sets the minimum number of processes to sporn to handle the incomming connections.
# On large sites you might want to try 32. minchildren = 32 


# sets the minimum number of processes to be kept ready to handle connections.
# On large sites you might want to try 8. minsparechildren = 8


# sets the minimum number of processes to sporn when it runs out
# On large sites you might want to try 10. preforkchildren = 10 


# sets the maximum number of processes to have doing nothing.
# When this many are spare it will cull some of them.
# On large sites you might want to try 64. maxsparechildren = 64 


# sets the maximum age of a child process before it croaks it.
# This is the number of connections they handle before exiting.
# On large sites you might want to try 10000. maxagechildren = 5000



# Process options
# (Change these only if you really know what you are doing).
# These options allow you to run multiple instances of DansGuardian on a single machine.
# Remember to edit the log file path above also if that is your intention.

# IPC filename
# 
# Defines IPC server directory and filename used to communicate with the log process. ipcfilename = '/tmp/.dguardianipc'

# URL list IPC filename
# 
# Defines URL list IPC server directory and filename used to communicate with the URL
# cache process. urlipcfilename = '/tmp/.dguardianurlipc'

# PID filename
# 
# Defines process id directory and filename.
#pidfilename = '/var/run/dansguardian.pid'

# Disable daemoning
# If enabled the process will not fork into the background.
# It is not usually advantageous to do this.
# on|off ( defaults to off ) nodaemon = off

# Disable logging process
# on|off ( defaults to off ) nologger = off

# Daemon runas user and group
# This is the user that DansGuardian runs as.  Normally the user/group nobody.
# Uncomment to use.  Defaults to the user set at compile time.
# daemonuser = 'nobody'
# daemongroup = 'nobody'

# Soft restart
# When on this disables the forced killing off all processes in the process group.
# This is not to be confused with the -g run time option - they are not related.
# on|off ( defaults to off ) softrestart = off

maxcontentramcachescansize = 2000 maxcontentfilecachescansize = 20000 downloadmanager = '/etc/dansguardian/downloadmanagers/default.conf' authplugin = '/etc/dansguardian/authplugins/proxy-basic.conf'
```

Squid.conf

```
http_port 3128
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?
acl QUERY urlpath_regex cgi-bin \?
cache deny QUERY
acl apache rep_header Server ^Apache

#broken_vary_encoding allow apache
access_log /squid/var/logs/access.log squid
hosts_file /etc/hosts
auth_param basic program /squid/libexec/ncsa_auth /squid/etc/userbasic.auth
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm proxy
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
auth_param basic casesensitive off

refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

acl NoAuthNec src <HIDDEN FOR SECURITY>
acl BrkRm src <HIDDEN FOR SECURITY>
acl Dials src <HIDDEN FOR SECURITY>
acl Comps src <HIDDEN FOR SECURITY>
acl whsws dstdom_regex -i .opensuse.org .novell.com .suse.com mirror.mcs.an1.gov mirrors.kernerl.org www.suse.de suse.mirrors.tds.net mirrros.usc.edu ftp.ale.org suse.cs.utah.edu mirrors.usc.edu mirror.usc.an1.gov linux.nssl.noaa.gov noaa.gov .kernel.org ftp.ale.org ftp.gwdg.de .medibuntu.org mirrors.xmission.com .canonical.com .ubuntu.
acl opensites dstdom_regex -i .mbsbooks.com .bowker.com .usps.com .usps.gov .ups.com .fedex.com go.microsoft.com .microsoft.com .apple.com toolbar.msn.com .contacts.msn.com update.services.openoffice.org fms2.pointroll.speedera.net services.wmdrm.windowsmedia.com windowsupdate.com .adobe.com .symantec.com .vitalbook.com vxn1.datawire.net vxn.datawire.net download.lavasoft.de .download.lavasoft.com .lavasoft.com updates.ls-servers.com .canadapost. .myyellow.com minirick symantecliveupdate.com wm.overdrive.com www.overdrive.com productactivation.one.microsoft.com www.update.microsoft.com testdrive.whoson.com www.columbia.k12.mo.us banners.wunderground.com .kofax.com .gotomeeting.com tools.google.com .dl.google.com .cache.googlevideo.com .gpdl.google.com .clients.google.com cache.pack.google.com kh.google.com maps.google.com auth.keyhole.com .contacts.msn.com .hrblock.com .taxcut.com .merchantadvantage.com .jtv.com .malwarebytes.org www.google-analytics.com dcs.support.xerox.com .dhl.com .webtrendslive.com javadl-esd.sun.com javadl-alt.sun.com .excelsior.edu .dhlglobalmail.com .nessus.org .foxitsoftware.com foxit.vo.llnwd.net installshield.com .mindjet.com .mediascouter.com media.us.elsevierhealth.com .xplana.com .govtrack.us sa.tulsacc.edu .omniture.com fpdownload.macromedia.com webservices.amazon.com
acl password proxy_auth REQUIRED
acl all src all
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8
acl SSL_ports port 443 563 631 2001 2005 8731 9001 9080 10000
acl Safe_ports port 80 # http
acl Safe_ports port 21 # ftp
acl Safe_ports port # https, snews 443 563
acl Safe_ports port 70 # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210 # wais
acl Safe_ports port # unregistered ports 1936-65535
acl Safe_ports port 280 # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488 # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 10000
acl Safe_ports port 631
acl Safe_ports port 901 # SWAT
acl purge method PURGE
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl UTubeUsers proxy_auth "/squid/etc/utubeusers.list"
acl RestrictUTube dstdom_regex -i youtube.com
acl RestrictFacebook dstdom_regex -i facebook.com
acl FacebookUsers proxy_auth "/squid/etc/facebookusers.list"
acl BuemerKEC src 10.10.128.0/24
acl MBSsortnet src 10.10.128.0/26
acl MSNExplorer browser -i MSN
acl Printers src <HIDDEN FOR SECURITY>
acl SpecialFolks src <HIDDEN FOR SECURITY>
# streaming download
acl fails rep_mime_type ^.*mms.*
acl fails rep_mime_type ^.*ms-hdr.*
acl fails rep_mime_type ^.*x-fcs.*
acl fails rep_mime_type ^.*x-ms-asf.*
acl fails2 urlpath_regex dvrplayer mediastream mms://
acl fails2 urlpath_regex \.asf$ \.afx$ \.flv$ \.swf$
acl deny_rep_mime_flashvideo rep_mime_type -i video/flv
acl deny_rep_mime_shockwave rep_mime_type -i ^application/x-shockwave-flash$
acl x-type req_mime_type -i ^application/octet-stream$
acl x-type req_mime_type -i application/octet-stream
acl x-type req_mime_type -i ^application/x-mplayer2$
acl x-type req_mime_type -i application/x-mplayer2
acl x-type req_mime_type -i ^application/x-oleobject$
acl x-type req_mime_type -i application/x-oleobject
acl x-type req_mime_type -i application/x-pncmd
acl x-type req_mime_type -i ^video/x-ms-asf$

acl x-type2 rep_mime_type -i ^application/octet-stream$
acl x-type2 rep_mime_type -i application/octet-stream
acl x-type2 rep_mime_type -i ^application/x-mplayer2$
acl x-type2 rep_mime_type -i application/x-mplayer2
acl x-type2 rep_mime_type -i ^application/x-oleobject$
acl x-type2 rep_mime_type -i application/x-oleobject
acl x-type2 rep_mime_type -i application/x-pncmd
acl x-type2 rep_mime_type -i ^video/x-ms-asf$
acl RestrictHulu dstdom_regex -i hulu.com
acl broken dstdomain cms.montgomerycollege.edu events.columbiamochamber.com members.columbiamochamber.com public.genexusserver.com
acl RestrictVimeo dstdom_regex -i vimeo.com
acl http_port port 80

#http_reply_access deny deny_rep_mime_flashvideo
#http_reply_access deny deny_rep_mime_shockwave

#streaming files
#http_access deny fails
#http_reply_access deny fails
#http_access deny fails2
#http_reply_access deny fails2
#http_access deny x-type
#http_reply_access deny x-type
#http_access deny x-type2
#http_reply_access deny x-type2

follow_x_forwarded_for allow localhost
acl_uses_indirect_client on
log_uses_indirect_client on

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access allow purge localhost
http_access deny purge
http_access allow SpecialFolks
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow whsws
http_access allow opensites
http_access deny BuemerKEC !MBSsortnet
http_access deny BrkRm RestrictUTube RestrictFacebook RestrictVimeo
http_access allow RestrictUTube UTubeUsers
http_access deny RestrictUTube
http_access allow RestrictFacebook FacebookUsers
http_access deny RestrictFacebook
http_access deny RestrictHulu
http_access allow NoAuthNec
http_access allow BrkRm
http_access allow FacebookUsers RestrictVimeo
http_access deny RestrictVimeo
http_access allow Comps
http_access allow Dials
http_access allow Printers
http_access allow password
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny SSL_ports !CONNECT
http_access allow http_port
http_access deny all
http_reply_access allow all

icp_access allow all

access_log /squid/var/logs/access.log squid
visible_hostname proxy.site.com
forwarded_for off
coredump_dir /squid/cache/
#header_access Accept-Encoding deny broken

#acl snmppublic snmp_community mysecretcommunity
#snmp_port 3401
#snmp_access allow snmppublic all

cache_mem 3 GB

#acl snmppublic snmp_community mbssquid
#snmp_port 3401
#snmp_access allow snmppublic all
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you got authentication turned on for both Squid and DansGuardian? Because it sounds like it. Disable authentication in Squid and then try connecting through DansGuardian again.